# writing $^*$ in R's matplot

Tags: r, plot, expression

I'm trying to represent `$r^*$` in R matplot:

```
expression(r^*(bold(X)))
```

but the interpreter seems to get caught at the `'^*'` part. 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,expression(r^"*"*(bold(X))))
```

A raw `*` is used to separate (juxtapose) the plotted expressions, see `?plotmath`. Here, you wish to print an asterisk as plain text.